# Range sum supporting dynamically adding data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, range

I am looking for a data structure that can do range-sums like a Segment tree but can support adding a new piece of data at any time without rebuilding the entire tree. I believe I can hack together a segment which can handle adding new data dynamically but it wouldn't be pretty.

If it helps, I will always be "appending" data since it is time based.

Example:

```
Order[time=0, quantity=1]
Order[time=1, quantity=2]
Order[time=2, quantity=4]
Order[time=3, quantity=2]
```

Range sum segment Tree:

```
                sum[0->3=9]
    sum[0->1=3]             sum[2->3=6]
time0=1     time1=2     time2=4     time3=2
```

What would happen to the tree above if I added `Order[time=4, quantity=3]`

```
                                        sum[0->4=12]
               sum[0->3=9]                                        sum[4->4=3]
    sum[0->1=3]           sum[2->3=6]                  sum[4->4=3]
time0=1     time1=2   time2=4     time3=2          time4=3
```

I can certainly use the approach above but I am hoping there is something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are always appending data at consecutive time values, you could consider simply storing the cumulative sum of all the quantities in an array.

Your example of 1,2,4,2 would make the array 1,3,7,9:

```
1
1+2=3
1+2+4=7
1+2+4+2=9
```

You can then do a sum of values over a range of elements by subtracting two elements of the cumulative array.

This is O(1) for append and O(1) for a range sum.

Comment: Interesting and simple, my example above was a bit simpler then my actual use case. Let me see if I can apply the same idea to my data.

Comment: @Justin Updates (as opposed to appends) would be very expensive (`O(n)`) under this model, but it might be a good fit if you don't expect many of those.

Comment: There will be no updates to previous data; so that is not a concern.

Comment: @Justin In that case this will work better for you than Fenwick trees - their advantage is fast updates, and they give up a bit of speed in fetches to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand your problem, but it sounds like you're looking for a [Fenwick tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).  From an array, a Fenwick tree can be built in `nlog(n)`, they allow summing over a contiguous range in `log(n)`, and you can update a node in `log(n)`.  I'm not sure about extending the array; I've never tried that, but I expect it would be `log(n)` as well.

Comment: Yea, I was looking at a Fenwick tree also but it started looking less appealing when I wanted to "resize" the underlying array. It's still an option.

Comment: @Justin If it sounds like it would help, and being able to extend the array by one index in `log^2(n)` time would be quick enough, I can try to write up the algorithm.  I think that would be the worst-case time.  If you explain the problem in more detail, I might be able to help more - I'm not terribly familiar with Segment trees.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the algorithm, if you get the time to write it up.